# Promise array for Q.all

Tags: arrays, angularjs, request, q, angular-promise

I have an array of links, which I get in first request. My goal is to go to every link to gather data. So I want to make a promise for every request, push them all into an array and then pass to Q.all to resolve all the promises. The problem is I can't return promise and go to the next link
Here is the function, where I tried to make multiple requests and gather data

```
function arrayPromise(linksArr){

function collectingData(elem){
    var deferredNew = Q.defer();
    var url = elem;
    request(url, function(error,response,html){
        if(error){
            deferredNew.reject(error);
        }
        var $ = cheerio.load(html);
        var title, content;

        $('.entry-title').filter(function(){
            var data = $(this);
            var title = data.text();
            items.text.push(
                {  titleof: title }
            )
        })

        $('.entry-content ').filter(function(){
            var data = $(this);
            var content = data.html();
            items.text.push(
                { contentof: content})
        })
        deferredNew.resolve(items);
    })
    console.log("Returning the promise");
    return defferedNew.promise;
}

var promiseArr;
console.log("LENGTH:");
console.log(linksArr.length);

for (var i = 0; i < linksArr.length; i++) {

    console.log(linksArr[i]);

    var tempPromise = collectingData(linksArr[i]);
    console.log(tempPromise);
    promiseArr.push(tempPromise);

};
    return promiseArr;
}
```

And how I try to use it

```
var linksPromise = fetchLinks();
linksPromise.then(function(arr){
    console.log("LINKS PROMISE RESOLVED");

    Q.all(arrayPromise(arr)).then(function(data){
        console.log("SUCCESS RESOLVING ALL PROMISES")
        console.log(data);
    },function(err){
        console.log("ERROR RESOLVING ALL PROMISES", err);
    });
},function(err){
    console.log(err);
})
```

Comment: _then pass to Q.all to resolve all the promises_ - I think you misunderstand the function of `Q.all`. It doesn't resolve the promises passed in, it resolves when all the promises in the passed in array resolve, or rejects when any one of those promises rejects

Comment: I understand that. I think error may not be in Q.all, but rather in function that generates array of promises

Answer (score 0):

promiseArr should be declared as an array:

```
var promiseArr = [];
```

If that doesn't fix it, please provide the error that you might be seeing.

Comment: That's a good point, but nothing changes. I don't see any errors. It seems that the function inside for-loop never returns.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Are you console logs firing?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't. It looks like script is stuck in the function inside the for loop

Comment: comment out your request function. At the same time please paste your request function.

Comment: Please also console log arr, that you pass in.

Comment: I don't understand what do you want me exactly to console.log. After `var tempPromise = collectingData(linksArr[i]);` I can't console.log anything

Comment: console.log("LINKS PROMISE RESOLVED", arr);

Comment: Can you get a jsfiddle up and running.

Comment: Sure. But because it's running in node.js. I decide to use this service instead of jsfiddle: https://ide.c9.io/b1rd/server-example

Answer (score 0):

There are MULTIPLE problems
First is in

```
    deferredNew.resolve(items);
```

`items` is defined in a local scopes not defined anywhere in scope where `deferredNew.resolve(items);` evaluated.

Another: Assigning empty array to `promiseArr` would help too.

One more: `request(url, function(error,response,html)` is not assigning result anywhere and your function has no return statement where you think you return promice `deferredNew.resolve(items);`

PS
There are more erros, check that all your function return value, for example   `$('..').filter(...)` does not reurn values